# Contest with unique vote

Tags: rating

My users can submit Recipes (a custom content type). I want to create a contest to let my users vote for their unique favorite recipe.

To vote, users (anonymous users) have to go to the page of the recipe they want to vote for and clic on "I vote for this one" to vote for it. If they go to another recipe page, they won't be able to vote for it because they would have already voted for another recipe.

Do you have any idea about how to do it ?

I know how to do it with a poll inside a block but I want to have a vote button inside each recipe page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a way to do it with Rate or Five Stars.

My solution is pretty simple : webforms. You can allow only one "vote" per ip with this module and you can create a view / block to display it on each node.

It does everything I needed !